# Не срабатывает replace внутри функции

Tags: javascript, функции, replace, return

```js
function format(n) {
  return n.replace('.', ',') + "%";
  //return n + "%"; 
}

var h = format(3.5);
alert(h);
```

Нужно заменить точку на запятую, то есть результат должен быть `"3,5%"`. `Replace` должен быть внутри функции, надо осуществить для `ionRangeSlider`. Преобразования n в число или строку так же не помогли.

Comment: передается число, у числа нет метода `replace`, если привести это число к строке - все заработает

Comment: Извините за уточнение, вы отметили ответ как принятый вот за эту фразу: _а ты суешь цыфору_? Или какой был критерий оценки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace` работает со *строками*, а ты передаешь *число*

Можно решить так:

```js
const format=(n)=>(`${n}`.replace('.', ',') + '%');

let outputin = format(3.5);
console.log(outputin);
```

Или через `.toString()` так:

```js
const format=(n)=>(`${n.toString().split('.').join(',')}%`);

let outputin = format(3.5);
console.log(outputin);
```

Answer (score 5):

передается число, у числа нет метода replace, если привести это число к строке - все заработает

```js
function format(n) {
  return n.toString().replace('.', ',') + "%";
  //return n + "%"; 
}

var h = format(3.5);
console.log(h);
```